# Help Finding where ROS is Installed

Tags: ros

This is rather embarrassing, but I cannot find where ROS is installed on my robot. I recently took it over from a past team who I cannot get in contact with. I'm trying to create a node to read from the /tf topic and print the position to a CSV, but I cannot find where ROS is installed to create my subscriber.
I know that /tf is installed at /opt/ros/noetic/share/tf and that I have noetic installed, but cannot get any further than that.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll need to be specific. Clearly, `/opt/ros/noetic` exists, as it should, and that *is* where ROS is installed. Perhaps you are trying to find your company's custom catkin workspace?